# subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_2^{p}$ up to permutation equivalence

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2:= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1\}$.
Let $p$ be a prime integer. We use 
$$\mathbb{Z}_2^{p}:= \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cdots \times\mathbb{Z}_2\qquad (p-times).$$
i.e., each $x\in \mathbb{Z}_2^{p}$ can be written as $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_p)$ where for each $1\leq i\leq p$, $x_i\in \{0,1\}$.
I want to determine all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_2^{p}$ up to permutation equivalence (up to isomorphism). I have no idea how to do this. So, I would like to ask if someone can provide a numerical example,say for $p=5$.
Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you men by "up to permutation equivalence." Do you mean with $S,T\subseteq G$ then $S\sim T$ if there is an automorphism $\phi:G\to G$ such that $\phi(S)=T$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews exactly, by a fixed permutation of the places. Thanks.

Comment: There is a difference between a permutation and an automorphism. Considering permutations, there is exactly one equivalence for subsets of size $n$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots,2^p$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain it using an example?

Comment: You wrote the question. Show what the answer should be when $n=2$, for example.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I read "fixed permutation of the places" as permutation matrices, not all permutations.